# How to enumerate the solutions of a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When we solve a quadratic equation, and let's assume that the solutions are $x=2$,  $x=3$, should I say

1. $x=2$ and $x=3$
2. $x=2$ or $x=3$.

What is the correct way to say it?

Comment: The answer "The solutions are $x=2$ and $x=3$" is perfectly fine, sounds a little better than "or." If we leave out "the solutions are" then I would say the balance tilts to or.

Comment: The second way is better.  $x$ can't be both $2$ and $3$ at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x$ cannot *simultaneously* equal both $2$ and $3$, you need to use $x = 2$ **or** $x = 3$.

You can say that both $x = 2$ and $x = 3$ are solutions to the equation, but that simply means that when $x = 2$, the equation is satisfied, and when $x = 3$, the equation is satisfied. But clearly, when $x = 2, x\neq 3$ and when $x = 3, x \neq 2$.  I.e. it makes no sense to say $x = 2 = 3$, e.g. solves the equation.

Comment: Always clean +1

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you write the solution.

$(x-2)(x-3)=0$, so $x=2$ or $x=3$.

$(x-2)(x-3)=0$, so the solutions are $x=2$ and $x=3$.

Comment: Are you the same as this person? http://math.stackexchange.com/users/43115/jasper-loy

Comment: Why? You mean user17762?

Comment: Oh No I am not Jasper loy. Absolutely not

Answer (score 3):

You should say $$x=2 \color{red}{\textbf{ or }}x=3.$$ $x=2$ and $x=3$ is wrong since $x$ cannot be equal to $2$ and $3$ simultaneously, since $2 \neq 3$.